# El Capitan freezes then Shutdown on MBP 15"

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, performance

I have some strange behaviour in my MBP 15" (Early 2013) with fresh El Capitan installation. Sometimes it freezes for about 20 seconds then shuts down with no message.
This began after changing screen with stagnate problem.

How to identify this problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: even after some syntax edits, I still don't understand "This began after changing screen with stagnate problem." Could you edit & clarify exactly what you mean?

Comment: ooh, sorry - i mean staingate problem :) damn autocorrect :) i cannot remember similar problem before display change, but after - it causes about once or two times per week